# Remove Space Disk Cygwin

Tags: location, cygwin, package

I have installed Cygwin with more than half the whole package available. Unluckly for me the installation has been interrupted as the laptot turn into low-power standby...  I could not take back the installation and I noticed that it has taken around 6GB of disc space. So i wonder if you could help me to remove those useless previous package files.. I am on windows 7.

Thank you in advance

Comment: First installation or upgrade ? Do you want to remove all the installation or only a portion of the packages ?

Comment: It is an upgrade installation  with more package and presently  i would like to remove all the installation with all the packages ... (i switch on VM and i need more space disk). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: To remove all cygwin is enough to remove the directory. Same for the cache download.